# From HTTP1.1 to HTTP2 - getting error -gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, http, gcc, apache2

I am trying to run the following PHP code on ubuntu20.04 on Apache2 server:

```
<?php 
  exec("gcc /path/main.c -o /path/main.out 2> /path/compile-error.txt");
  $compile_error = file_get_contents("/path/compile-error.txt");
  echo "<pre>$compile_error</pre>";
  $output = exec('/path/main.out');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

The main.c file contains the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
int main() { 
  printf("Hello, World!");    
  return 0; 
}
```

The code was running fine and was displaying “Hello World!”.

Then I enabled HTTP2 (all steps followed as shown below – disabling **mpm_prefork** and enabling **mpm_event**).

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-fpm
sudo a2dismod php8.1 
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo service apache2 restart && sudo service php8.1-fpm restart
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and added Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
sudo a2enmod http2
sudo a2enmod mpm_event proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo apachectl configtest && sudo service apache2 restart
```

The HTTP2 is running fine. But the above-mentioned code gives the following error:

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Please note that I am still able to run the command on shell successfully but not through http.
I have tried the following steps to resolve it but it was not successful:

- Reinstalled gcc
- Reinstalled build-essential

Comment: I think HTTP2 itself is a red herring here, but it sounds like you've made a number of system changes - "all steps followed as usual" doesn't really tell us what, but changing from mpm_prefork (one process per request) to mpm_event (one _thread_ per event) implies you've probably _also_ changed how PHP is configured (e.g. switched to a thread-safe build, or from Apache module to external FastCGI manager). The resulting question is a bit hard to follow without knowing what your system is and what you've done to it.

Comment: I have followed the following steps while implementing HTTP2: 
1. `sudo apt-get install php8.1-fpm`
2. `sudo a2dismod php8.1` 
3. `sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm`
4. `sudo service apache2 restart`
5. `sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork`
6. `sudo a2enmod mpm_event`
7. `sudo service apache2 restart && sudo service php8.1-fpm restart`
8. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and added `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1`
9. `sudo a2enmod http2`
10. `sudo a2enmod mpm_event proxy_fcgi setenvif`
11. `sudo apachectl configtest && sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Right - please can you click [edit] and add that information in place of the "... as usual". As I thought, you've switched from running PHP as an Apache module to running it via FPM (FastCGI Process Manager). That probably means you have a new php.ini file which needs configuring; it may also mean PHP is running as a different user.

Comment: It looks like I need to configure php.ini (new). Please guide me on where to focus.